# C - Understanding structure's value setting pattern

Tags: c, memory, structure

i have built a small c program which i am trying to set a structure value

```
**static faut fautData**

typedef struct
{
    char ds[25];
    char ec[51];
    char vc[51];
    char rc[51];
    char rb[2];
    char eb[2];
    char vb[2];
    char es[10];
    char dias[50];
    char ss[10];
} faut;
```

i have a function name update to set values for the above specified structure

but when i try to set ** **faut.es** ** @ the beginning of the update function the value does not get assigned(in my print call it does not get reflect.

when  i set the same value @ the end i i am able to print the output and see the value

why is that??

sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char ds[25];
    char ec[51];
    char vc[51];
    char rc[51];
    char rb[2];
    char eb[2];
    char vb[2];
    char es[10];
    char dias[50];
    char ss[10];
} faut;


typedef struct
{
    unsigned int d5;
    unsigned int d10;
    unsigned int d20;
    unsigned int d50;
    unsigned int d100;
    unsigned int d500;
    unsigned int d1000;
    unsigned int an;
    unsigned int rn;
    unsigned int cn;
    int alr;

}ncd;

static ncd chkncd;
int cdc;

void admin_init(void)
{
    char Keys[17];
    int i = 0;
    int keysEnabled;
    int shift = 0x01;
    keysEnabled=0xFF;
    strcpy(Keys,"0000000000000000");
    //keysEnabled = getKeysToEnable();
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {

        switch((keysEnabled & shift))
        {
            case 0x10:
                Keys[0]=0x34;
                Keys[1]=0x36;
                break;
            case 0x20:
                Keys[2]=0x34;
                Keys[3]=0x37;
                break;
            case 0x40:
                Keys[4]=0x34;
                Keys[5]=0x38;
                break;
            case 0x80:
                Keys[6]=0x34;
                Keys[7]=0x39;
                break;

            case 0x08:
                Keys[8]=0x34;
                Keys[9]=0x34;
                break;
            case 0x04:
                Keys[10]=0x34;
                Keys[11]=0x33;
                break;
            case 0x02:
                Keys[12]=0x34;
                Keys[13]=0x32;
                break;
            case 0x01:
                Keys[14]=0x34;
                Keys[15]=0x31;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        shift = shift << 1;
    }
    printf("%s",Keys);

}

void update(void)
{
    char temp[512];
    int i = 0;
    static faut fautData;
    memset(&fautData, '\0', sizeof(fautData));
    int cat =0;
    if(cat) // Any failure
    {
        strncpy(fautData.ds, "3", 1);
        strncpy(fautData.es, "4", 1);
        memset(temp,'\0',sizeof(temp));
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy(fautData.es, "2",1);
        strncpy(fautData.ds, "0",2);
    }
    strcpy(&fautData.ec[0],"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");//00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    strcpy(&fautData.rc[0],"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");//00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    strcpy(fautData.vc,"");
    if(chkncd.d50 != 0){
        memset(temp,'\0',sizeof(temp));
        strcat(fautData.vc,"01");
        sprintf(temp, "%03d", chkncd.d50);
        strcat(fautData.vc,temp);
    }
    if(chkncd.d100 != 0){
        memset(temp,'\0',sizeof(temp));
        strcat(fautData.vc,"02");
        sprintf(temp, "%03d", chkncd.d100);
        strcat(fautData.vc,temp);
    }

    if(chkncd.d500 != 0){
        memset(temp,'\0',sizeof(temp));
        strcat(fautData.vc,"03");
        sprintf(temp, "%03d", chkncd.d500);
        strcat(fautData.vc,temp);
    }
    if(chkncd.d1000 != 0){
        memset(temp,'\0',sizeof(temp));
        strcat(fautData.vc,"04");
        sprintf(temp, "%03d", chkncd.d1000);
        strcat(fautData.vc,temp);
    }
    sprintf(fautData.vb, "%02d", chkncd.an);
    fautData.rb[0] = 0x30;
    fautData.rb[1] = 0x30;
    fautData.eb[0] = 0x30;
    fautData.eb[1] = 0x30;
    strncpy(fautData.dias, "0", 1);
    cdc = cdc - chkncd.an - chkncd.cn;
    if ((chkncd.alr) || (cdc < 2450))
        strncpy(fautData.ss, "4", 1);
    else
        strncpy(fautData.ss, "1", 1);
    sprintf(temp,"keysEnabled:\nds : %s\nec : %s\n vc : %s\nrc : %s\n rb : %s\n eb : %s\n vb : %s\n es : %s\n ss : %s\n",   fautData.ds,    fautData.ec,    fautData.vc,    fautData.rc,    fautData.rb,    fautData.eb,    fautData.vb,    fautData.es,    fautData.dias,  fautData.ss);
    printf("%s",temp);
}



int main(void) {

    cdc=2300;
    chkncd.d5=0;
    chkncd.d10=0;
    chkncd.d20=0;
    chkncd.d50=0;
    chkncd.d100=0;
    chkncd.d500=1;
    chkncd.d1000=0;
    chkncd.alr=0;
    chkncd.an=1;
    chkncd.rn=0;
    chkncd.cn=0;
    update();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: if i put strncpy(fautData.es, "2",1); after sprintf(fautData.vb, "%02d", chkncd.an); it works perfectly..

Comment: That's because that `sprintf` call is your problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
sprintf(fautData.vb, "%02d", chkncd.an);
```

`fautData.vb` is two bytes, but your `sprintf` call will write three bytes: the two-digit number followed by a null terminator, which overflows the `vb` array and overwrites `fautData.es`.

Comment: Easiest thing to do would be to `sprintf` to a temp buffer of adequate size then just `memcpy` the first two bytes from that buffer to `vb`.

Comment: I prefer allocating enough space - if you use the method you propose, then printing `.vb` will run past the end of the string, into the `.es` string.

Comment: @Floris Allocating enough space would definitely be the best solution, but that struct format may be constrained by factors he can't control.  If he can enlarge it, I agree he should.

Comment: @Floris the constraint i have is the protocol.The documentation refers that it to be 2 bytes. (its required for client parsing)

Comment: If he can't, then he needs a different print statement. He cannot print the value of a 2 character string when it is not `nul` terminated, using `"%s"`. He could use "%.2s" to limit it to printing just two characters (and it won't notice the lack of `nul`)..

Comment: @Floris I don't understand what you mean.  He's printing an int, not a string.  So the simplest solution still appears to me to be printing it to a temp buffer and then just copying the first two bytes from that buffer to `vb`.

Comment: I'm talking about printing the result later - when he is inspecting the contents of the structure. At that point, if you do `printf("%s", fautData.vb);`, and there is no `nul` termination  on that string, you will print `vb` followed by `es`. See my updated answer for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
strncpy(fautData.es, "2",1);
```

you are copying "at most 1 character". This leaves you without the terminating null, and that can cause a problem. As the description says:

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if
>   source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not
>   be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would
>   overflow).

You need to do

```
strncpy(fautData.es, "2",2);
```

to make sure you have a valid string.

Further, in your line

```
sprintf(fautData.vb, "%02d", chkncd.an);
```

You are putting a `'\0'` after `.vb` (so really you are writing three characters in total). But since `vb` only has space for two characters, the nul will be put as the first element of the next structure element - which happens to be `.es`. Thus, when you try to print `.es`, the first character is "end of string", and nothing gets printed.

If you change the `struct` to have three elements of space for vb:

```
char vb[3];
```

the problem goes away.

This is a tricky thing that happens all the time; you need one more space for each string than you have "characters". That `'\0'` takes space...

**update** as you said that you are constrained to have two bytes, you have to limit yourself to printing just two characters to the structure element during writing - and you have to limit yourself to printing only two characters during printing. Example:

```
void set_vb(int value) {
  char temp[3];
  sprintf(temp, "%02d", value);
  memcpy(fautData.vb, temp, 2);
}

void print_vb(void {
  printf("%.2s", fautData.vb);
}
```

Now you can forget "how to do it right", and just call these two functions when you need to set or print the value of `vb`. You could do  the same for other elements where you run into this issue (given the tight size of your struct, that could apply to many of them...)

Comment: He's `memset`ting `fautData` at the beginning of the function, so that should be harmless.